# Initialize an Array and accept arguments at runtime

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I build an Array with multiple values accepted from the user at run time?

For e.g., we have in c++ like:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){ cin>>a[i]; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
Array.new(10){gets.chomp}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gets`:

```
a = []
10.times{|i| a[i] = gets.chomp}
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/BI6W)

Comment: Or just `a << gets.chomp`

Comment: Or `a = 10.times.map { gets.chomp }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = []
10.times{a.push(gets.chomp)}
```

Comment: The second line, though correct, does not return `a`. You could write `10.times.map { gets.chomp }`, which does.